# How to reduce size and increase speed of Unity iOS Build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am working on a relatively small 2D game. Anytime a build it in unity for iOS to test on a device the folder size is north of 900MB and it takes several minutes to build. I have checked `Developement Build` and set `Run in Xcode as` to `Debug`. Basically, these are the only settings I have adjusted from the defaults. How can I possibly reduce the folder size or increase the build speed?

Comment: 900MB? Sounds like you should be looking for some overlarge assets in the project. Recommend you check the [editor log](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html), which includes a disk usage breakdown for each build you make. Textures and audio can get very large if you're not careful.

Comment: yes, most probably it's audios - check that your audios have Vorbis as import format, not PCM. 3mb Vorbis = 30mb PCM

Comment: I don't have a Unity folder at ` ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log` which is the location for Mac OS X users. Also just realized that in the Libraries folder there's a `libiPhone-lib.a` file that's 920MB. Is there a way to build and add this as a library to the code when the build is complete or is it just a necessary evil?

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick and two that can be used to build faster. First when you build to iOS in debug mode, remeber to enable Symlink Unity Libraries to generate the XC project faster. Also in the Player settings select the scripting backend "mono" when you are testing the game in Development mode, this makes it buid 50% faster in XC. ( you cannot release with the mono backend so you will have to build and do your final testing in IL2CPP mode).

Also you can do bytecode stripping as well as using the micro mscorelib to make XC take less time, and lastly make sure that you dont have to transfer alot of unused resources to the device every time you start it again..

Hope this will help and Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure Unity will only compile whats being used inside your scenes. 
Correct me if I am wrong, but if you have textures or sprites that not referenced by anything then it wont be included into the xCode build or for the build for an .apk file.

My experience is it takes several minutes to get my project from Unity->Xcode->Phone, generally five-ten minutes.

This has actually been consistent with all the apps I've made.

"and it takes several minutes to build" Unless its ten minutes or 20-30 minutes, I would say just deal with it and wait.